# Remove a list of array items

Tags: javascript, lodash

Can you tell me how to remove a list of array items using [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove)? I have tried as shown below.But it is not working.

[**Video about the issue.**](https://youtu.be/890YXOt6uwA)

```
  _.remove(previousNumberArray, (a) => {

         _.some(this.removedQuestionCodes, (val, k) => {
            return a.questionCode == val.questionCode;
        });

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the bracket `{}` 
for arrow function inside `{}` should have `return`

Let's try

```
  _.remove(previousNumberArray, (a) => _.some(this.removedQuestionCodes, (val, k) => {
       return a.questionCode == val;
  }));
```

**Or**

```
  _.remove(previousNumberArray, (a) => {

         return _.some(this.removedQuestionCodes, (val, k) => {
            return a.questionCode == val;
        });

   });
```

Let's see my example:

```js
var fruits1 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Celery'];

_.remove(fruits1, fruit => {//BRACKET
  //MUST HAVE RETURN KEYWORD
  return _.indexOf(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'], fruit) !== -1
});

var fruits2 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Celery'];
_.remove(fruits2, fruit => {//BRACKET
  //DONT HAVE RETURN KEYWORD
  _.indexOf(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'], fruit) !== -1
});

console.log('fruits1',fruits1)


console.log('fruits2', fruits2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.6.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nope.None of above 2 solutions are working.Do you know why? It doesn't remove any item from the original array `previousNumberArray`.

Comment: So can you give an example of 2 arrays? I guess there are some problem with your _some

Comment: Glad to know that help :)